# Static implementation on ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

So I have an odd set of circumstances, which basically requires a static implementation attached to an Active Record object.  Here is the background.

I have a `Product`, which is sold by one or more `Provider` (`has_many_through :product_providers`).  However, each `Provider` has a specific set of rates for each `Product` based on a request form, consisting of unique rates (dollar amounts) and algorithms.  Due to the complexity of the algorithms, they are stored in separate Ruby classes.

What I'm trying to accomplish is how to associate a `ProductProvider` with a static class.  My first implementation was something along the lines of:

```
# slug = 'acme-widget'
slug.split('-').join('/').camelize.constantize
```

This would give me the class,  `Acme::Widget`.  This technically works, but I feel like there must be a better pattern.

Comment: Generally, the approach seems good enough. Slightly shorter would be `slug.gsub('-','/').camelize.constantize`. Or, I suppose you could create a custom inflection.

Comment: how many of these static classes do you have? If you only have a few `Acme::Widget`-types, it may just be faster (and safer) to just map them to a hash `{'acme-widget' => Acme::Widget}`

Comment: At the moment, there are ~63 ProductProviders.  So not a small number.

Answer (score 1):

I've previously solved this (overall) problem using the [classy_enum](https://rubygems.org/gems/classy_enum) gem: it takes care of getting from the database-stored value to the right class instance, and brings some other enum conveniences along for the ride.

However, it's been some time since I last used it, and the gem is now [no longer actively maintained](https://github.com/beerlington/classy_enum/blob/14a8822220a714b02c5d5617e543a5e11984751e/CONTRIBUTING.md). While it would still be a good fit for your problem, it might need some updates to work with Rails 5.0+.

---

If you're going to implement it yourself, be careful when calling `constantize` on possibly-user-affected input. A static hash would be safest; a scoped `const_get` `ProviderStrategy.const_get(s)`, or a `constantize` on a restricted string (`"Provider::#{s}".constantize`), is next best.

This is important because if a [malicious] user is able to choose an arbitrary constant in the running system, it will *generally* just error when it fails to respond to a required method, but [there are always tricky edge cases](https://www.sitepoint.com/anatomy-of-an-exploit-an-in-depth-look-at-the-rails-yaml-vulnerability/).

Comment: The input is mostly coming from Seeds, with the slug being read only.  So I’m not apocalyptically worried about user input.  Just seems like this might be a common pattern I’m just not seeing.  Thank you.